# Problem setting style for a element created using DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am facing problem in setting style for a 'tr' element,created using DOM inside javascript.
the code is like-

```
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
tr.onmouseover=function(){this.style.backgroundColor='#fbf9e0';};
                     or
tr.attachEvent('onmouseover',this.style.backgroundColor='#fbf9e0';);
```

am runnig this code in IE-7. Any other approch?

Comment: [JavaScript is for behavior, not for presentation](http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/#introduction). You should do styling in CSS and apply a class using JavaScript.

Comment: @WTP, I agree for the most part.  But I'd treat it as a guideline and not a hard-set rule.  There are (true, rare) times where it makes more sense to tweak a style in script.

Comment: @Kon I said 'should' because I also treat it as a guideline. If it were a rule it won't be possible to do elsewise.

Comment: @WTP-there is already a class attached to the TR.And that class can not be modified. Can i Add those style and hover in another class??Or can I add more than 1 class to a element,i guess no.

Answer (score 1):

Is jQuery an option?  If so, this becomes pretty simple:

```
$('tr').live('mouseover', function() {
   $(this).css('background-color', '#fbf9e0');
});
```

This will attach the mouseover event handler to every TR, whether it's present in the DOM now or will be in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Using `attachEvent` allows you to attach more than one event to an object.

Using `onmouseover` when you set it, it can be overridden

Answer (score 0):

As a comment mentioned, I would suggest the following: Either use a global style, or a class-specific one with the pseudo-class `:hover`.

```
tr:hover {
  background-color: #fbf9e0;
}

/* or */
tr.someClass:hover {
  background-color: #fbf9e0;
}
```

If you go that class route, make sure to add it to the object:

```
<script>
  tr.className = 'someClass';
</script>
```